# Is there a method to multiply only certain elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

Suppose I have a numpy array like so:

```
a = ([[4, 9], [38, 8], [90, 10]...[8545, 17]])
```

Where the first element is a location ID and the second is the amount of time spent at each location in minutes. I want to convert these times into seconds which requires me to multiply every other value by 60.

As this is a very long array, what would be the most time-efficient method for converting these times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
import numpy as np
# a is your original list of [location, time] pairs
a = np.array(a)
a[:, 1] *= 60
```

It simply multiplies the second column of your array `a` by 60 to convert the time values into seconds.

Comment: Thank you, much simpler than the `for` loop I was trying to use

Comment: You'd be better off using `a[:, 1] *= 60`. It's an in-place operation and won't allocate a temp array.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: Thanks for the comment. Noted.